# setting a placeholder attribute with translation in Symfony2 form input

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle for managing my users. In order to register user, I reused the form of the bundle which meets my needs. Nevertheless, I needed to set some attributes of my fields. This is was done easyly by twig like this:

```
    {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': "span12",
        'placeholder': "Username"} }) }}
```

Now, my goal is to make automatic translation on my placeholder, so I proposed this code:

```
    {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': "span12",
        'placeholder': "{{'security.login.usernameplaceholder'|trans}}"} }) }}
```

This previous code produced an input with placeholder value equal to **{{'security.login.usernameplaceholder'|trans}}**

To get rid of this problem, I tried to set variable for that but symfony generated an error!!!

```
    {% set usernameplaceholder = {{'security.login.usernameplaceholder'|trans}} %}
    {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': "span12",
        'placeholder': usernameplaceholder} }) }}
```

Is there any proposition to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Twig you shouldn't put `{{` within `{{` (same for `{%`); think of it as the php tag.

The following should work

```
{% set usernameplaceholder = 'security.login.usernameplaceholder'|trans %}
{{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': "span12",
    'placeholder': usernameplaceholder} }) }}
```

OR

```
{{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': "span12",
    'placeholder': 'security.login.usernameplaceholder'|trans} }) }}
```

Answer (score 7):

### For Symfony 3.x, 4.x

Another way to add placeholders (or **any attributes** for that matter) is by passing an **options-array** to the form `$builder` containing another **Array `attr`** with attributes as key-value pairs.

```
// The parameters are column name, form-type and options-array respectively.
$builder->add('field', null, array(
            'attr' => array(
                 'placeholder' => 'support.contact.titleplaceholder'
             )
        ));
```

Comment: I did a little testing in Symfony 3.4 and it seems that this will not be translated automatically. Any suggestions on how to get the translation with this approach?

Comment: I wonder about this as well, does seem to get auto translated

Comment: you could add in another attribute `'translation_domain' => 'fooo'` where fooo refers to your translation file **fooo.de.xlf** as per this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236605/how-to-translate-labels-in-symfony2-forms-with-messages-en-yml/28746416)

Answer (score 1):

You can translate this way as well (Using symfony4) in twig:
In a form placeholder wich would be written like this:

```
{'attr':{'placeholder': "Text to translate"}}
```

As for a placeholder in html wich would be written like this, you can translate this way:

```
<input placeholder="{{"Text to translate"|trans }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the placeholder in the [form-type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#form-types) (and not in the template) you must the placeholder inside the `attr` option. For example:

```
->add('search', TextType::class, ['attr' => ['placeholder' => 'form.custom.placeholder']])
```

To have the placeholder then translated in the background, you must [adjust the form-theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#creating-a-form-theme-in-a-separate-template).
In our case we wanted to trigger automatic translation only if the [translation_domain](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#translation-domain) is set explicitly in the form-type. This is how we achieved automatic translation:

```
{% block form_widget_simple -%}
    ....
    {% if attr.placeholder|default and translation_domain|default %}
        {%- set attr = attr|merge({placeholder: (attr.placeholder|trans({}, translation_domain))|trim}) -%}
    {% endif %}
    ....
{{- parent() -}}
{%- endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

If you want to always trigger automatic translation. This should work:

```
{% block form_widget_simple -%}
    ....
    {%- set attr = attr|merge({placeholder: (attr.placeholder|default|trans({}, translation_domain))|trim}) -%}
    ....
{{- parent() -}}
{%- endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also add it to your form definition like this:

```
    $builder
        ->add('information', 'textarea', array(
            'label' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank()
            ], 
            'attr' => [
               'placeholder' => 'support.contact.titleplaceholder'
            ]
        ));
```

Comment: placeholder should be inside the "attr" like: 'label' => false, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'support.contact.titleplaceholder'..

Comment: @numediaweb Updated