# How to translate labels in symfony2 forms with messages.en.yml?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, translation, formbuilder

I am trying to get translation of form fields to work. I have `messages.en.yml` in my Bundle's Ressource folder.

```
test: it works
form:
    description: Add a description.
```

I want to build a form in an `EntityType` which translates the labels of the form fields accordingly.

```
$builder->add(
    'description',
    null,
    array('label' => 'form.description', 'required' => false)
);
```

Yet only the literal string `'form.description'` gets shown, not the expected translation of `Add a description.`

The translation service and the `messages.en.yml` are loaded correctly as I can call

`var_dump($this->get('translator')->trans('test'));`

in a controller and get the translated result.

What am I missing when I want to treat the string `'form.description'` as something that should be translated?

I suppose I have to call the trans function on them anyhow, yet how can I make it in one go automatically?

Comment: OK, weird. Now it just works. I don't as of yet know what changed but I will look into it. I suspect some weird cache issue that persisted even after cache:clear

Comment: Currently having the same issue. Any idea what caused it?

Comment: @ferdynator For me, I suspect it was a caching error. If `clear:cache` does not work, try purging the dev cache manually via `rm -rf app/cache/dev/*`. Also, check if you have a typo in the yml-name. It also could be an lower-vs-uppercase issue.

Comment: @ferdynator Was the upvote from you and did it resolve the issue you were facing? If so, I add it as an answer.

Comment: An easy trap to fall into is also not activating it in the config: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#configuration

Answer (score 42):

i had to explicitly set the translation domain

e.g

```
->add('description','hidden',
 array(
   "label"=>"form.description",
   "required"=>true,
   'translation_domain' => 'fooo'
 )
);
```

in case of

```
fooo.de.xlf
```

Comment: for me unfortunately this approach did not work, but the translation was loaded. I checked this with the trans function of the translation helper

The issue might be the way I use the form in the twig template.
{{- form_label(child) -}}

Answer (score 6):

In symfony 3.1 You don't need to pass translator to form type constructor. It will be translated automatically by form field name like this:

Controller action:

```
$form = $this->createForm(LoginType::class);
```

FormType class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('username',
            TextType::class, ['label_format' => '%name%',]
        );
}
```

And your translations file (yml):

```
username: Your translation for username field
```

Hope it will help someone:)

Comment: Is a specific way to print the form required to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Add translation in form for is best idea - because found if in twig much more easy

```
{% trans_default_domain 'YourNameBundle' %}

{{'shot.tag.for.transle'|trans }}
```

also you must remember about translation file in your bundle,
if you extend bundle from another (example - you extends FosUserBundle)
you can take translate from this bundle or use func *trans* with params

```
{{'shot.tag.for.transle'|trans({}, 'TranslationNameBundle') }}
```

Have a nice localisation.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to translate into French. Then you have **filename.en.xlf** and **filename.fr.xlf**.

now for the following form element you want to make **description** translatable.

```
$builder->add(
    'description',
    null,
    array('label' => 'form.description', 'required' => false)
);
```

so in the **filename.en.xlf**

```
<trans-unit id="17">
    <source>description</source>
    <target>description</target>
</trans-unit>
```

and for French, so in the **filename.fr.xlf** as below

```
<trans-unit id="17">
    <source>description</source>
    <target>fr descrip</target>
</trans-unit>
```

hope this will help for someone

Comment: You dont show how to actually translate the form label. You show a label being used and the translation files being set but the add does not translate by default and especially not if your message codes are in special domain files.