# Can not set checkbox label from twig

Tags: symfony, checkbox, translation, symfony-2.8

I would like to set translated label for checkbox using twig. In [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html#label) it is said that I can set label like this:

```
{{ form_widget(search_form.matched, { 'id': 'matched' }) }}
{{ form_label(search_form.matched, 'only_matched'|trans({}, 'offers')) }}
```

Unfortunatelly label is not changing at all. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not work this way. I used to declare Twig variable for this purpose and that worked for me. According to your code, it will be something like this:

```
{% set var = 'only_matched'|trans({}, 'offers') %}

{{ form_widget(search_form.matched, { 'id': 'matched' }) }}
{{ form_label(search_form.matched, var) }}
```

Check also this issue: [How to translate labels in symfony2 forms with messages.en.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236605/how-to-translate-labels-in-symfony2-forms-with-messages-en-yml)
Here is a lot of similar solutions.

Comment: YOur solution didn't work, but the one from link below worked :)

Comment: @IgnasDamunskis, it worked nicely on my staging server. I'll debug it more carefully, but I am glad that my link helped you.