How to translate the automatic Symfony FileType input placeholders or labels?
I'm trying to translate the automatic placeholders or labels for a Symfony FileType.
Specifically, I want to change the text "Escolher ficheiro" e "nenhum ficheiro selecionado" to their English and French equivalents.
Here is how the input is being displayed
Here’s what I have in my form builder:
->add('avatar', FileType::class, [
                'required' => false,
            ])

And in my Twig template:
<div class="col mb-2">
    <label for="partner-info-avatar" class="form-label label-without-bg mb-0">
        {{ 'forms.labels.image'|trans }}
    </label>
    {{ form_widget(form.avatar, { attr: { class: "form-control", type:"file", id:"partner-info-avatar", enctype:"multipart/form-data"} }) }}
    <div class="form-errors">
        {{ form_errors(form.avatar) }}
    </div>
</div>

This is the file type code that I'm using
What I've tried:

I attempted to change the placeholder attributes directly in the form builder, but it didn't affect the input.

I want to customize and translate the default text that appears in the file input field. How can I achieve this in Symfony and Twig?

Please see https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html to learn the Symfony translation basics and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769748/setting-a-placeholder-attribute-with-translation-in-symfony2-form-input to find a solution for your problem.

Thank you, Anton, but I think that it isn't that. I think that the input appearence is defined by the browser. I tried to change the browser's standard language and the text of the input also changed to the new language

The placeholder value can be defined by setting the placeholder attribute of a input tag (or textarea or so). In Symfony: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707663/how-to-add-placeholder-on-input-in-symfony-4-form - the value is translatable, see link above.

That was my first attempt but then I realized that this input appearance and text are defined by the browser. Thanks anyways! :)

Then, you can try it by using CSS - see frontend frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap how it can be done.
